# UnknownHostException occur when intract with MQTT?

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I develop an app that perform **MQTT** operation and also interact with a **Bridge**(by connecting the bridge using wifi just like we connect some one's wifi).

> 1->When direct interact with **MQTT**  all operation of mqtt work like connect,subscribe and publish the data and getting the data from **MQTT**.

> 2->When I interact with  Bride and again trying to interacting with **MQTT** it throws Exception.

```
MqttException (0) - java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "iot.rkl.com": No address associated with hostname
1608604152.272 9629-9629/com.asiczen.azlock W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
1608604152.272 9629-9629/com.asiczen.azlock W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:690)
1608604152.275 9629-9629/com.asiczen.azlock W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:75)
1608604152.275 9629-9629/com.asiczen.azlock W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:92)
1608604152.275 9629-9629/com.asiczen.azlock W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:676)
```

Here the service class that perform **MQTT** operation

```
public class MqttMessageService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = MqttMessageService.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String EXTRA_DATA = "android.nfc.extra.DATA";
    public static final String MQTT_CONNECTED = "android.nfc.extra.MQTT_CONNECTED";
    public static final String MQTT_DISCONNECTED = "android.nfc.extra.MQTT_DISCONNECTED";
    public static final String MQTT_DATA_AVAILABLE = "android.nfc.extra.MQTT_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public static final String MQTT_DELEVIERY_COMPLETED = "android.nfc.extra.MQTT_DELEVIERY_COMPLETED";
    public static final String MQTT_UNABLE_TO_PUBLISH = "android.nfc.extra.MQTT_UNABLE_TO_PUBLISH";
    public static final String MQTT_UNABLE_TO_SUBSCRIBE = "android.nfc.extra.MQTT_UNABLE_TO_SUBSCRIBE";
    public static final String MQTT_USUBSCRIBE = "android.nfc.extra.MQTT_USUBSCRIBE";
    public static final String MQTT_UN_SCBSCRIBE = "android.nfc.extra.MQTT_UN_SCBSCRIBE";

    private MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;

    public void connectMQTT(){
        Log.d(TAG, "MQTT CONNECTION STAR: ");
        PahoMqttClient pahoMqttClient = new PahoMqttClient();
        mqttAndroidClient = pahoMqttClient.getMqttClient(getApplicationContext(), Packet.PublishTopic.MQTT_BROKER_URL, AppContext.getClientId(this));

        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectComplete: ");
                Log.d(TAG, "MQTT CONNECTED: ");
                broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_CONNECTED);
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d(TAG, "connectionLost: ");
                Log.d(TAG, " MQTT CONNECTION LOST: ");
                broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_DISCONNECTED);
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) {
                //setMessageNotification(s, new String(mqttMessage.getPayload()));

                String msg = new String(mqttMessage.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
                Log.d(TAG, "MQTT MESSAGE ARRIVED: "+msg);
                byte[] b = mqttMessage.getPayload();
                broadcastUpdate(b);
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        Log.d(TAG, "MQTT ONCREATE: ");
        connectMQTT();
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalService();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MQTT ONBIND: ");
        return mBinder;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
        // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
        // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.
        //close();
        Log.d(TAG, "MQTT ONUNBIND: ");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
    public class LocalService extends Binder {
        public MqttMessageService getService(){return  MqttMessageService.this;}
    }

    public void subcribe(){
        try {
            //pahoMqttClient.subscribe(mqttAndroidClient, "BridgeId_SCAN_RESPONSE", 0);
            IMqttToken token = mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(Utils.getSubscribeTopic(), 0);
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "MQTT SUBSCRIBED 0: ");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Subscribe Successfully " + "BridgeId_SCAN_RESPONSE");
                    broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_USUBSCRIBE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Subscribe Failed " + "BridgeId_SCAN_RESPONSE");
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_UNABLE_TO_SUBSCRIBE);
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_UNABLE_TO_SUBSCRIBE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_UNABLE_TO_SUBSCRIBE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void msubscribe(String topic){
        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(topic, 0);
            Log.d(TAG, "MQTT SUBSCRIBED 1: ");
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void publish(byte[] payload){
        Log.d(TAG, "publish: ");
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(payload);
        message.setId(320);
        message.setRetained(false);
        message.setQos(0);
        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.publish(Utils.getPublishTopic(), message);
            Log.d(TAG, "MQTT DATA PUBLISHED: ");
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_UNABLE_TO_PUBLISH);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void unSubscribe(){

        IMqttToken token;
        try {
            token = mqttAndroidClient.unsubscribe(Utils.getSubscribeTopic());
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "UnSubscribe Successfully ");
                    Log.d(TAG, "MQTT UNSUBSCRIBED: ");
                    broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_UN_SCBSCRIBE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "UnSubscribe Failed ");
                    broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_UN_SCBSCRIBE);
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            broadcastUpdate(MqttMessageService.MQTT_UN_SCBSCRIBE);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect()  {
        try {
            IMqttToken mqttToken = mqttAndroidClient.disconnect();
            mqttToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "MQTT DISCONNECTED: ");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Successfully disconnect");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failed to disconnect " + throwable.toString());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(byte[] data) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MqttMessageService.MQTT_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, data);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Below Paho connection calss

```
public class PahoMqttClient {
public MqttAndroidClient getMqttClient(Context context, String brokerUrl, String clientId) {
        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(context, brokerUrl, clientId);
        try {
            MqttConnectOptions MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = getMqttConnectionOption();
            if (brokerUrl.contains("ssl")) {
                InputStream i=  context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client_ca);
                InputStream i1=  context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client_crt);
                InputStream inputStream =  context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.client_key);
                MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS.setSocketFactory(createSSLSocketFactory(i,i1,inputStream));
            }
            IMqttToken token = mqttAndroidClient.connect(MQTT_CONNECTION_OPTIONS);
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts(getDisconnectedBufferOptions());
                    Log.d(TAG, "MQTT CONNECTED:0 ");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "MQTT CONNETION FAILED:0 ");
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Failure " + exception.toString());
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return mqttAndroidClient;
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with the Bridge.  Anyhow, this sounds like a networking problem rather than a programming problem.  That exception means that your app was unable to talk to a DNS service that knows how to resolve "iot.rkl.com".

Comment: But when i direct interact with MQTT it work properly not getting any exception.Exception occur only after interacting with bridge.how do i solve it.

Comment: *"how do i solve it?"*.  You need to figure out what is wrong with the "bridge".  I don't think this is a programming question.  Try asking on a Q&A site for Android problems or networking problems or some such.

Comment: Or you could just wait and *hope* that an Android networking wizard passes through and waves a magic wand ...

Comment: But after sending and getting data from bridge the socket is closed successfully then where is problem on bridge side.

Comment: And for Ios it work properly on above 2 condintion.